# Imap_fetch_overview and newest / oldest mail

Tags: php, imap

I am struggling with sequence for imap_fetch_overview. Is the mail 1 the oldest or newest mail? If a new mail arrives does it get a higher id or not?

Solution:

```
   $check = imap_check($connection);
   $result = array();   

   if($check->Nmsgs > 0){

        $sort = imap_sort($connection, SORTARRIVAL, 0);

        $msgs = '';

        $i = 1;

        foreach($sort as $id)
        {
            if($i > 200) break;
            $msgs = $msgs . $id . ',';
            $i++;
        }

        $response = imap_fetch_overview($connection, rtrim($msgs,','));
        foreach ($response as $msg){
            $result[] = $msg;
        } 
    }
```

Comment: not sure they are sorted, see `imap_sort()` and the related information in documentation.

Comment: So based on the imap_sort I build a string I pass to imap_fetch_overview ?

Comment: your edit may return a bunch of the most recent, but not necessarily in order within that return.  this may be a performance tradeoff.  see http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetch-overview.php#88235

Comment: if you provide the sequence list as your code indicates, according to this (http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetch-overview.php#33631) it will still return the results lowest to highest UID which may not be date

Answer (score 1):

For the second part of the question,

**see this [RFC](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc822/) .**

Each mail will have different ID but there is no higher or lower. It is just rendomly selected but unique.

For the first part of your question,

If you want to find oldest or newest mail, you have to use `date` method like:

```
$overview = imap_fetch_overview($connection,$email_number,0);
echo $overview[0]->date;
```

then compare this mails using returned dates.